# Why two vectors are same even the have different origin

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Let a vector with coordinate point A with coordinates (4, 5, 6) to point B with coordinates (10, 11, 12). the vector joining them is 6i+6j+6k which is same as position vector of point (6,6,6) so how two different things have same vector

Comment: A vector gets completely and unequivocally determined by its length and by its direction **only** .  Thus, two finite segments of straight line with the same direction (if you want, think of them as being part of two *parallel* lines) and with the same length are **exactly the same**. There is no left or right, up and down in vectors...and that's what makes them so increidibly useful. Finally, **as vectors**,both $\;\vec{(6,6,6)-(0,0,0)}=\vec{(6,6,6)}\;$ and, say $\;\vec{(7,10,3)-(1,4,-3)}=\vec{(6,6,6)}\;$ are **exactly the same**, no matter where their "beginning" is.

Comment: what is the usefulness of this idea

Comment: First, you can use this to solve many geometrical problems with analytic geometry. In fact, it is probably the most powerful tool for that together with trigonometry and geometry itself. You can check in google (I suppose) for proofs of geometric theorems with it...It also has lots of uses in physics and other sciences, in economy, statistics and etc.

Comment: please give some examples

Comment: Read this:  https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-applications-of-vectors-in-real-life and also this: https://www.adelaide.edu.au/mathslearning/bridging/resources/MT3VectorsBook_Feb2013.pdf

Answer (score 1):

It could help to think about a physical example.  If you walk from point $A$ to point $B$, then the vector $\overrightarrow{AB}=\langle 6,6,6\rangle$ represents your displacement:  You moved 6 units in the $x$-direction, 6 in the $y$-direction and 6 in the $z$-direction.  If you start at the origin $O$, and then walk to the point $C=(6,6,6)$, then your displacement is the same as before.  You've moved 6 units in the $x$-direction, 6 in the $y$-direction and 6 in the $z$-direction.

Answer (score 0):

Right. In general, the vector $\vec{AB}$ is the same as $B-A$, which is sometimes called a *free vector*.

Free vectors are the same as vectors based at the origin.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#Overview.